# How to get the data from list without using iterator in c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, iterator, containers

i have a list contains set of strings, i want to fetch the data present in the list based on index, with out using iterator.. is there any functions like get() or getat() some sort of method using which we can fetch?

Comment: provide some more specifics as in the **list** is it a List<string> or its some other collection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

myList[index] is the way to go

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
myList.Add("string 1");
myList.Add("String 2");

Console.WriteLine(myList[0]); // string 1
Console.WriteLine(myList[1]); // String 2
```

Answer (score 6):

```
List<string> myList = new List<string();
//add some elements to the list
//then get the third element
string thirdElement = myList[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
item = list[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the overloaded index operator.

```
List<String> list; // ... initialize, populate list
String element = list[1]; // get the element at index 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your collection implements `IList<T>`, just use indexer. Otherwise, if your collection only allows forward-only access (that is, only implements `IEnumerable<T>`) you can use `ElementAt()` method, but it still uses iterator under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of list you're talking about exactly, but most collections in .net have a `CopyTo` function, and you can access individual items with the `[]` operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("lots of strings");

//If you want to print all the strings you can do:
foreach(string str in list)
   Console.WriteLine(str);

//If you want to modify each string in the list, make each lower case for example, 
// you can do. this is working by using the index of the elements in the list:
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
   list[i] = list[i].ToLower();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the generic type **List** (or another implementation of **IList**) you can use the index operator to directly access items at certain positions: `item = myList[3]`

If you use a type that only implements **IEnumerable** you should use the `ElementAt()` function.

What's your reason to avoid the use of iterators?